Does child component re-render or re-initialize in Angular?
I am new to Angular(14) and i am facing a issue. when i update a property of parent component which is an array then the child component get re-initialize(ngOnInit function is running).
Facing this issue when using child component in a for loop.
// parent Component ts file
students: string[] = ['student1', 'student2', 'student3', 'student4'];
  updateName(value: string, index: number) {
    console.log(index);
    this.students[index] = value;
  }
// template of Parent component
<app-search 
      *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index" 
      [student]="student"
      (changeName)="updateName($event, i)"
    >

// Child component ts file
searchValue = '';
@Input() student!: string;
  @Output() changeName = new EventEmitter<string>();
  updateName() {
    this.changeName.emit(this.searchValue);
  }
// template of Child component
<div class="search-container">
    <span>
        Search:
    </span>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
    <p>{{searchValue}}</p>
    <p>Student Name: {{student}}</p>
    <button (click)="updateName()">Update</button>
</div>

when i am updating a name input field is getting blank. I write this code just to understand how it work(i know there migth not be any use of this kind of code).
Facing this issue when using child component in a for loop.
It would be good if i get any reference of this.

you should pass trackBy to align instances in the "old array" vs "new array". *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index; trackBy: trackById" and a method on the component trackById(idx: number; stud: Student) {return stud.id;} or other value that can  be a unique identifier for a student

In the NgForOf loop, angular needs to be able to uniquely identify each item rendered so it can perform DOM updates to that component in case of change.
So how do you help the directive to uniquely identify elements?
We can do that by providing a trackByFn so if any property updates in that element, the directive and update that component instead of rendering it.
How to use trackByFn?
Its just a function that's gonna receive the item in param and you ( developer ) will return a unique prop on that object.
// HTML
<ng-container *ngFor="let student of students; let i = index;  trackBy: trackFn">
  <app-student [studentName]="student"></app-student>
</ng-container>

// TS
trackFn(student: Student) {
  return student.id;
}

See this stackblitz example StackBlitz TrackByFn
HOPE THAT HELPS : )
